# How to edit the value of id_semester according to the input using select?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

My function add on controller to model

```
$data['edit'] = $this->pengumuman->getEdit($id_pengumuman);
```

My function getEdit on Model

```
$this->db->select('mp.id_pengumuman, mp.judul_pengumuman, mp.isi_pengumuman, mp.start_date, mp.end_date, 
            mp.thn_ajaran, mp.id_semester, mb.beasiswa, mp.date_created, mp.user_created, mp.is_publish')
        ->from('tbl_mst_pengumuman mp')
        ->join('tbl_mst_beasiswa mb', 'mp.id_beasiswa=mb.id_beasiswa', 'left')
        ->group_by('mp.id_pengumuman')
        ->where('mp.id_pengumuman', $id_pengumuman);
        return $this->db->get()->row();
```

My form on view

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <label>Semester<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <select name="id_semester" id="id_semester" class="form-control input-sm">
   <option value="0">--Pilih Semester--</option>
   <option value="1" <?= ($edit->id_semester == @$edit->id_semester) ? "selected":""; ?>>Ganjil</option>
   <option value="2" <?= ($edit->id_semester == @$edit->id_semester) ? "selected":""; ?>>Genap</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

In `id_semester` there is value 1 = Odd, 2 = Even. The problem is when the edit value of `id_semester` cannot be displayed properly. All ids display 2 = Even.

Comment: Issue not clear. pls explain

Comment: what is an issue??

Comment: In id_semester there is value 1 = Odd, 2 = Even.
the problem is when the edit value of id_semester can not be displayed properly. all id display 2 = Even.

sorry, my english is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the view, fix the condition so it will selecting the right `id_semester` :

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <label>Semester<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <select name="id_semester" id="id_semester" class="form-control input-sm">
   <option value="0">--Pilih Semester--</option>
   <option value="1" <?= ($edit->id_semester == '1') ? "selected":""; ?>>Ganjil</option>
   <option value="2" <?= ($edit->id_semester == '2') ? "selected":""; ?>>Genap</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, fix